# How to have a table with two kinds of variable colums

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Question and there is two kinds os questions, the T/F questions and the multiple choise questions.
Is it possible to make a dynamic table contains the general colums of the Question and the specific colums of the T/F questions and the multiple choise questions?

Can anyone help me how to create the model to solve this problem ? Thanks .

Comment: Post the table schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your questions and their choices into separate tables. Have a third table that defines the mapping between the questions and their options. Having your tables normalized would help avoid repeating option groups like True and False.

Here's a rough UML sketch of the table schema:

[image: Database Tables Diagram]

*You'd need to add Primary/Foreign Key **constraints** as well to your tables. I've omitted them for brevity.*

```
CREATE TABLE QUESTIONS
    (`Question_ID` int, `Question_Text` varchar(50), `Answer_ID` int);

INSERT INTO QUESTIONS
    (`Question_ID`, `Question_Text`, `Answer_ID`)
VALUES
    (1, 'True/False question?', 1),
    (2, 'Multiple-choice question?', 5);

CREATE TABLE OPTIONS
    (`Option_ID` int, `Option_Text` varchar(25));

INSERT INTO OPTIONS
    (`Option_ID`, `Option_Text`)
VALUES
    (1, 'TRUE'),
    (2, 'FALSE'),
    (3, 'Option 1'),
    (4, 'Option 2'),
    (5, 'Option 3'),
    (6, 'Option 4');

CREATE TABLE QUESTION_OPTIONS
    (`QnA_ID` int, `Question_ID` int, `Option_ID` int);

INSERT INTO QUESTION_OPTIONS
    (`QnA_ID`, `Question_ID`, `Option_ID`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 1, 2),
    (3, 2, 3),
    (4, 2, 4),
    (5, 2, 5),
    (6, 2, 6);
```

Now, just join the tables to fetch all the relevant details for a question.

```
SELECT Option_Text,
  CASE
    WHEN q.Answer_ID = o.Option_ID THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END Is_Answer
FROM QUESTIONS q, OPTIONS o, QUESTION_OPTIONS qo
WHERE qo.Option_ID = o.Option_ID
  AND q.Question_ID = qo.Question_ID
  AND q.Question_ID = 1

SELECT Option_Text,
  CASE
    WHEN q.Answer_ID = o.Option_ID THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END Is_Answer
FROM QUESTIONS q, OPTIONS o, QUESTION_OPTIONS qo
WHERE qo.Option_ID = o.Option_ID
  AND q.Question_ID = qo.Question_ID
  AND q.Question_ID = 2
```

***Output*** :

```
+--------------+-----------+
| OPTION_TEXT  | IS_ANSWER |
+--------------+-----------+
| TRUE         |         1 |
| FALSE        |         0 |
+--------------+-----------+

+--------------+-----------+
| OPTION_TEXT  | IS_ANSWER |
+--------------+-----------+
| Option 1     |         0 |
| Option 2     |         0 |
| Option 3     |         1 |
| Option 4     |         0 |
+--------------+-----------+
```

You can tweak the tables if you like at **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f49a1/10)**.

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for, Thank you so much for your work and for your time.

Comment: Sorry to bother , but the column QnA_ID in the table QUESTION_OPTIONS is necessary? the composite key with the other two columns(Question_ID and Option_ID) wouldn't be more efficient?

Comment: @DanielCoelho Using a composite key here is perfectly fine. Usually a surrogate key is preferred if the columns that make up the composite key can change (as it would then trigger changes to the index as well). Since, here we have PK/FKs only in the composite it wouldn't be a problem. Personally, I prefer single-column surrogate keys as they are easier to join on in the queries too. It's totally your call. Both are fine here.

Answer (score 0):

This solution handles both T/F questions and multiple choice questions:

[image]

Comment: im afraid i didnt explain correctly what i want, i have a table Question, but there are two kinds os questions, the T/F questions and the multiple choise questions. Is it possible to make the table Question dynamic so she can be able to store the general colums of the question and the specific colums of the T/F questions or the multiple choise questions.
Example a question can be T/F and have the colums option A, text, isCorrect or a question can be multiple and have the colum correction(V/F).
Example, a Question can be

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a dynamic type in MySQL on a column. From what I understand you're building some sort of customizable trivia. Here's an approach that would allow you to have different type of answers for a question :

[image]

You could use a query somewhat like the following to retrieve the answer type : 
SELECT *
FROM 
Questions
LEFT JOIN 
WHERE

You could use a query somewhat like the following to retrieve the correct answer :

```
SELECT
    Questions.ID,
    IF(AnswersTF.ID IS NOT NULL, AnswersTF.Answer, NULL) AS 'TF',
    IF(AnswersChoices.ID IS NOT NULL, AnswersChoices.ID, NULL) AS 'Choice',
    IF(AnswersNumber.ID IS NOT NULL, AnswersNumber.Answer,NULL) AS 'Number',
FROM 
    Questions
    LEFT JOIN AnswersTF ON
        Questions.ID = AnswersTF.QuestionID
    LEFT JOIN AnswersChoices ON
        Questions.ID = AnswersChoices.QuestionID
    LEFT JOIN AnswersNumber ON
        Questions.ID = AnswersNumber.QuestionID
WHERE
    Questions.ID = ?
```

or

```
SELECT
    Questions.ID,
    CASE 
        WHEN AnswersTF.ID IS NOT NULL THEN AnswersTF.Answer
        WHEN AnswersChoices.ID IS NOT NULL THEN AnswersChoices.ID
        WHEN AnswersNumber.ID IS NOT NULL THEN AnswersNumber.Answer
        ELSE NULL
    END AS 'Answer'
FROM 
    Questions
    LEFT JOIN AnswersTF ON
        Questions.ID = AnswersTF.QuestionID
    LEFT JOIN AnswersChoices ON
        Questions.ID = AnswersChoices.QuestionID AND
        AnswersChoices.IsAnswer = 1
    LEFT JOIN AnswersNumber ON
        Questions.ID = AnswersNumber.QuestionID
WHERE
    Questions.ID = ?
```

You could use a query somewhat like the following to retrieve the multiple choices :

```
SELECT
    AnswersChoices.ID,
    AnswersChoices.Choice,
    AnswersChoices.IsAnswer
FROM 
    Questions
    JOIN AnswersChoices ON
        Questions.ID = AnswersChoices.QuestionID
WHERE
    Questions.ID = ?
```

Most of the time, there are multiple good answers on the topic of data modeling, so feel free to comment to specify your request if you think my answer doesn't fit. Hope this helps!